# Mapping Significance Level to Z-Scores

Tags: statistical-significance, z-score

Does a mapping (e.g. a table) exist, to map Z-scores to significance levels?
For the Normal Distribution, a Z-score of 1.96 corresponds to the 0.05 significance level.
How can the significance level be found for a Z-score of e.g. 2.1?

Comment: It is literally the  of the normal.

Answer (score 3):

Of course.  They can be found in the back of nearly any statistics textbook and look like those shown below:

You can even generate your own in R with the following command:

```
data.frame(Z=seq(-3,3,0.01), Prob=pnorm(seq(-3,3,0.01)))
```

[image]

or like this:

[image]